# How is the blanket recommendation to version RESTful APIs justified for web-only apps?

Tags: rest

The blanket recommendation that a RESTful API should be accessed through a version number (`/api/v1`, `/api/v2`, ..) is puzzling.

If the RESTful API will be accessed by a mobile app or a desktop program, then it's evident that versioning is necessary. Older apps/programs that are already installed on users' devices should continue to function when a breaking change is introduced to the API.

But suppose an app is purely a web app. The HTML5 served will always match the current API version. Is there any reason then to version the API, besides the potential future implementation of mobile apps or desktop programs targeting the same API?

Comment: I've always thought that recommendation was intended for public APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not at all a blanket recommendation. In fact, lots of folks argue that it's a bad practice. Like many best practices, there's people in either camp.

If you fully control the caller and the callee, then I think you can take a lot more liberty in terms of best practices can ignore. Something to keep in mind though, is that things, after being built, might take a life on their own get used in unexpected contexts. It can be a lot more expensive for rebuild something for a new use-case, rather than build something from scratch.

Especially if something is relatively easy to do (planning for versioning might be one), I think I am generally in the camp of doing things as well as possible and only ignore best practices in cases where there's a strong business case to do so. Saving a lot of time would be good one.